# Match String Tuple in Rust

Tags: rust

This is one of those simple-but-I-don't-know-how-to-do-it-in-rust things.

Simply put:

```
pub fn pair_matcher(tup: &(String, String)) {
    match tup {
        &("foo".as_string(), "bar".as_string()) => print!("foobar"),
        _ => print!("Unknown"),
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
-:3:17: 3:18 error: expected `,`, found `.`
-:3          &("foo".as_string(),"bar".as_string())=> { print!("foobar"); }
                    ^
```

How do you match this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left hand side of each branch of a match is not an expression, it is a pattern, which restricts what can go there to basically just literals (plus things like `ref` which change the binding behaviour); function calls are right out. Given how `String` works, it’s not possible to get one of them into a pattern (because you can’t construct one statically). It could be achieved with `if` statements:

```
if tup == ("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()) {
    print!("foobar")
} else {
    print!("Unknown")
}
```

… or by taking a slice of the `String`s, yielding the type `&str` which *can* be constructed literally:

```
match (tup.0.as_slice(), tup.1.as_slice()) {
    ("foo", "bar") => print!("foobar"),
    _ => print!("Unknown"),
}
```

Constructing a new `String` each time is an expensive way of doing things, while using the slices is pretty much free, entailing no allocations.

Note that the `.0` and `.1` requires `#![feature(tuple_indexing)]` on the crate; one can do without it thus:

```
 let (ref a, ref b) = tup;
 match (a.as_slice(), b.as_slice()) {
     ("foo", "bar") => print!("foobar"),
     _ => print!("Unknown"),
 }
```

Because, you see, the left hand side of a `let` statement is a pattern as well, and so you can pull the tuple apart with it, taking references to each element, with `(ref a, ref b)` yielding variables `a` and `b` both of type `&String`.

The [Patterns section of the guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html#patterns) goes into some more detail on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is that you need to cast types in the other direction:

```
match (tup.0.as_slice(), tup.1.as_slice()) {
    ("foo", "bar") => print!("foobar"),
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing `,` after the first action too? I thought pattern arms had to be separated by a comma.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: [The comma is not necessary if the action is a block.](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#match-expressions)